# How do I include internal redirect response headers in the subsequent request?

Tags: envoyproxy

I'm currently using Envoy's [internal redirects feature](https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/intro/arch_overview/http/http_connection_management#internal-redirects) to handle a redirect coming from an upstream service. The **redirect response includes HTTP headers that I would like to include in the subsequent request** that Envoy sends when it follows said redirects. Unfortunately, the Envoy docs state the following:

> The headers and body of the original request will be sent in the redirect to the new location.

Does this mean it's currently not possible to include the redirect response headers in the subsequent request? If so, does anyone have any suggestions as to how I can workaround this issue?

I was thinking I might be able to use a [Lua script](https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/configuration/http/http_filters/lua_filter#lua) which runs on the request flow to manually add the response headers into the subsequent request, however I don't think the script would have access to the previous responses HTTP headers.

###### Associated GitHub Issue

https://github.com/envoyproxy/envoy/issues/16777

###### Internal Redirect Policy Example

```json
"internalRedirectPolicy": {
    "maxInternalRedirects": 1,
    "predicates": [
        {
            "name": "envoy.internal_redirect_predicates.allow_listed_routes",
            "typedConfig": {
                "@type": "type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.internal_redirect.allow_listed_routes.v3.AllowListedRoutesConfig",
                "allowedRouteNames": ["..."]
            }
        }
    ],
    "allowCrossSchemeRedirect": true
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like we are trying to achieve the same behaviour. In the upstream service maybe you can add the headers before redirect ? And then fine tune it in the lua script ?

Would it be possible to post a snippet of how you are configuring internal_redirect_policy in the yaml ?

Comment: I can update my original question with the JSON snippet we are using for a redirect policy. I'm not sure I understand your questions about adding the headers before the redirect though... the upstream service sending the redirect response **is adding them to the response**

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to achieve this within Envoy's own configuration.

[Custom Response and Request Headers](https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/configuration/http/http_conn_man/headers#custom-request-response-headers)

While there are many more built-in variables available for downstream connections from the client; it is possible to pass around upstream data to response headers via

```
%UPSTREAM_METADATA([“namespace”, “key”, …])%
```

> Populates the header with EDS endpoint metadata from the upstream host
> selected by the router. Metadata may be selected from any namespace.
>
> In general, metadata values may be strings, numbers, booleans, lists,
> nested structures, or null. Upstream metadata values may be selected
> from nested structs by specifying multiple keys.. ..The namespace and key(s) are
> specified as a JSON array of strings...
>
> Upstream metadata cannot be added to request headers as the upstream host has not been selected when custom request headers are generated.

or using

```
%DYNAMIC_METADATA([“namespace”, “key”, …])%
```

> Similar to UPSTREAM_METADATA, populates the header with dynamic metadata available
> in a request (e.g.: added by filters like the header-to-metadata filter).
>
> This works both on request and response headers.

So, basically you will add a filter to the upstream response in order to map the desired information into your custom headers. Note: when Envoy does an internal redirect, it will automatically include the original request as
`“x-envoy-original-url: http://my.com/url”`